# Is it possible to add view (layout) to fragment other than using replace/add?

Tags: android, view, android-fragments

I have a fragment implementation which is showing some fragments in framelayout. I need to change it for adding some animation,so that when one fragment changes to another i can give some animation.
For this i need to **get the view of the currently showing fragment** and pass it to another method which deals with the animation.I tried with getview() and able to pass the view.

But problem is , for changing the fragments, replace() method is used.

So what happens is when i press on a fragment it is moving as per animation to new view which i got through getview() but data is not found.Also when i press back i can see the actual view with data.This happens due to replace fragment i using, i guess.

ALso view is coming twice.due to adding fragment replace and due to animation.I cant change the fragment usage because it deals with some other part.

***Is there any other way to display view in that fragment without using replace() (like some inflator)??***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.To do so I created a new layout and inflated it to a new view and added the fragments code in it.So that this view will be shown first and also fragment view will be replaced in that view.